# csf: how to override TCP_IN?

Tags: firewall, port, csf

I'm using `csf v14.05` on my Debian-8-based server.

In `csf.conf`, I have the following:

```
TCP_IN = "53,80,110,119,143,443,465,587,953,993,995"
```

I want to selectively override this in `csf.deny`, only for certain specific host/port combinations, as in the following example:

```
tcp|in|d=143|s=aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd # actual IP address dummied out
```

However, requests coming from `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` to port `443` are still being allowed.

I know that `csf.allow` rules override all other rules, and therefore, it appears that `TCP_IN` within `csf.conf` also behaves the same way.

Is there any way in `csf` to allow open access to a given port ***except*** for certain, selected IP addresses, like I am trying to do here?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a source of common confusion ...

TCP_IN allows all the ports listed, regardless of csf.allow (except the csf.allow rule is a deny rule)

So, if you really wanted to selectively allow access to a port, you would exclude it from TCP_IN of csf.conf ... and then have it in csf.allow